# Error MSB4062 when trying to build my CUDA program

Tags: cuda

I get the following error when I try to build my first GPU Program. Any suggestions what might be going wrong?

> Error 1   error MSB4062: The "Nvda.Build.CudaTasks.SanitizePaths" task
>   could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Program
>   Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\BuildCustomizations\Nvda.Build.CudaTasks.dll.
>   Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program
>   Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\BuildCustomizations\Nvda.Build.CudaTasks.dll'
>   or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly
>   and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a
>   public class that implements
>   Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.  C:\Program
>   Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\BuildCustomizations\CUDA
>   3.2.targets   70  4   gpu

Comment: Good chance upgrading the CUDA sdk would have solved this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902495/cuda-toolkit-5-production-release-and-visual-studio-2010-integration

Answer (score 5):

I have faced with this problem. So many searching on internet but I could not find anything. At last I recognize that I closed Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.1 features on Windows Features section in Control Panel.

to turn on Microsoft .Net Framework 3.5.1, you can easily follow these instructions;

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/5023-windows-features-turn-off.html.

I hope this solution will help you !

Answer (score 3):

I've come across this problem after upgrading my system to windows 10. It turns out that I have to reinstall Visual Studio because some dependent dlls have been moved to Windows.old folder.

Comment: By the way, my missing dependency file is Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v3.5.dll.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same error when I was compiling on a remote server. I think it was because I was logged in using Remote Desktop (RDP). When I logged in using VNC and compiled, the error no longer happened.

Note that it's impossible to even install the CUDA Toolkit via RDP, so this is unlikely to happen, unless you regularly use both methods to connect to a server.