# CUDA Toolkit 5 Production Release and Visual Studio 2010 Integration

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cuda

In the absence of the NVidia CUDA forum, does anyone have any idea how to fix this?
It looks like the VS integration of CUDA toolkit has a problem.

I just installed the production release version of the CUDA toolkit 5 (32-bit for laptops on Windows 7), replacing the release candidate (which worked well) and now I can't compile or build anything including CUDA samples.

Everything I have tried gives an error like:
...BuildCustomizations\CUDA 5.0.targets(360,9): error MSB4062:
 The "Nvda.Build.CudaTasks.ResolvePaths" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\BuildCustomizations\Nvda.Build.CudaTasks.v5.0.dll. 
 Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.

The "CUDA 5.0.targets" file (it is an XML file) has several UsingTask elements and I don't see any reference to the ITask class mentioned, but I am reluctant to start editing a file I do not understand.

A similar error is given for CUDA 4.2 if I switch Build Customisations.

This is using Visual Studio 2010 Professional.
Non-CUDA projects still compile and build.

Any suggestions on where to start?

Comment: I have the same problem using CUDA 5.0.32 (32-bit) with VS2010 on Win7 64-bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix, you need to install the 64-bit CUDA 5.0.32 SDK (the latest release of CUDA 5.0). It contains a newer version of Nvda.Build.CudaTasks.v5.0.dll than the 32-bit installer (date modified is 25/09/2012 not May-2012).

I had trouble copying the Dll to the correct location because it was in use by another process. To work-around this, I used a batch file executed using Windows SAFE_MODE with CMD prompt (use F8 at boot-time to select the safe-mode startup option).

The batch command (worked on my 64-bit windows system):
copy "[YOUR INSTALL PATH]\CUDA\v5.0\extras\visual_studio_integration\MSBuildExtensions\Nvda.Build.CudaTasks.v5.0.dll" "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\BuildCustomizations"

Make sure your props and targets are also copied from the SDK install folder.

Comment: Splendid. That fixed it, thanks. I must admit I was confused whether 64-bit in the choice of download referred to the operating system or the build target. Your answer clarifies that it must be the OS.

Answer (score 1):

This problem probably arise from Microsoft .NET Framework features are turned off.

I answered another question which is same with yours.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21666179/2700726